# delegate gets null when performWithSegue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

Im trying to send some info from a modal view to a delgate. But it seems like my delegate doesnt follow through, it gets null. It looks like this in IB https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vIVT.png.
**But it works if i remove the navigationController that is right before the modal view and use the buttons in the View.**
please help, ive tried for like 5 hours... :/

Heres the modalViewController code:
    #import 
    #import "Link.h"

```
@protocol modalViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)closeview;
-(void)saveLink:(Link *)link;

@end

@interface modelViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *url;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <modalViewDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)exitModal:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveLink:(id)sender;

@end
```

and .m:

```
#import "modelViewController.h"

@interface modelViewController ()

@end

@implementation modelViewController
@synthesize titel;
@synthesize url, delegate;

- (IBAction)exitModal:(id)sender {
    //[self.delegate closeview];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)saveLink:(id)sender {
    if (titel.text.length > 0 && url.text.length > 0) {

        NSString *urlen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url.text];

        Link *linken = [[Link alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlen]];
        linken.title = titel.text;

        NSLog(@"%@", delegate); **//returns null when pressing button** it returns null if i put it in viewDidLoad to..

        [self.delegate saveLink:linken];

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];



    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"warning" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
@end
```

the MasterViewController .h (that pushes the modalview:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "modelViewController.h"

@class DetailViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <modalViewDelegate>
....
```

and .m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;
@synthesize links;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"linkPush"]) {
        // Skicka länken till detaljvyn
        DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailVC.link = [self.links objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        NSLog(@"%@", detailVC);
    }

    //this is the modalview "pusher"
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"newLink"]) {

        modelViewController *mvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        mvc.delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"%@", mvc.delegate);
    }


}

- (void)closeview {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //[self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)saveLink:(Link *)link{

    NSLog(@"hello");
    [links insertObject:link atIndex:links.count]; //updates a Tableview and works fine if delegate is called

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your destination view controller is wrapped into a navigation controller, you have to refer to it differently in `prepareForSegue`:

```
UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
DetailViewController *dvc = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now setting the properties, including the delegate, should work.